# Pip install module

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i install module os without **os.system('pip install os')**

I have this:

```
listimport=["requests","shutil","shutil","styless","time","tkinter","openpyxl","html","datetime","importlib","string",
      "easygui","bs4","webbrowser","glob","tarfile","webbrowser","pathlib","platform","subprocess","tkinterweb",
            "jira","numpy","matplotlib","calendar","sys","math","math","parser","pyautogui","dateutil","xlwt"]
for x_imp in listimport:
    try:
        __import__(x_imp)
    except ImportError as e:
        os.system('pip install ' + x_imp)
```

but in order for this to work properly i need to install os first, can someone help?

os comes with python, but when i make the portable app will it send the os too?

Comment: `os` should be a default package that's installed with python, do you not have `os`??

Comment: Many of the modules in your list (not just `os`) are part of the standard library so you don't need to install them and `pip` will give an error message if you try.  This applies to modules `shutil`, `time`, `tkinter`, `html`, `datetime`, `importlib`, `string`, `glob`, `tarfile`, `webbrowser`, `pathlib`, `platform`, `subprocess`, `calendar`, `sys`, `math` (and I might have missed one). Consult https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html .

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `os` at the top of your file.

```py
import os
```

Kindly check this [list of built-in modules](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) that come with python installation which can come in handy.